# error while trying to set $JAVA_HOME (linux)

Tags: java, linux, command, export, java-home

I'm trying to set  up Minecraft Forge SDK. I need to set up the JAVA_HOME variable:

```
kiwi@kiwi-gigabyte:~/Desktop/forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180-src$ export $JAVA_HOME '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin'
bash: export: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386': invalid identifier
bash: export: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin': invalid identifier
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is this:

```
export VAR='value'
```

So use

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Bash:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin'
```

See how that works. No dollar sign and use equals, only difference.